# How to update a pirtucular column in a database?

Tags: codeigniter

```
    $credit = $this->db->select('credits');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('refferal_code',$refferal_code);
    $data1 = array('credits'=>$credit + 10);
    $this->db->update('users',$data1);
```

I need to update a column in a database..
When a user signs up, he will give a referral code.
I need to check whether that code exists in the database and need to update the referral code for the user by giving him with 10 more credits.
The above code shows error, Can anyone help me me figure why?

Comment: Can U tell Me Error Which is Coming In Output

Comment: object of class ci_db_mysql_driver could not be converted to string

Comment: Try Below Code If Does Not Work Then Tell Me

Comment: Hope So It 'll Work Fine For U

Comment: Use this `$this->db->from('users');$this->db->where('refferal_code',$refferal_code);
            $this->db->set('credits', 'credits+10', FALSE);
            $this->db->update('users');`

Comment: thank you its working... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$credit = $this->db->select('credits');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('refferal_code',$refferal_code);
$data = $this->db->get();
if($data->num_rows()>0)
{
     $res = $data->row_object();
     $this->db->where('refferal_code',$refferal_code);
     $update = $this->db->update('users',array('credits'=>$res->credits + 10));
}
```

**OR**
Simplest one as @Shaiful Islam mentioned in comment

```
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('refferal_code',$refferal_code); 
$this->db->set('credits', 'credits+10', FALSE);
$this->db->update('users');
```